# Doing something after AsyncTask finishes

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup

I am developing an android application which uses Jsoup to retrieve web content. To execute this, I am using separate `AsyncTask` classes. I need to show the retrieved results after the finish of `AsyncTask`s. The `doInBackground` method stores retrieved data into an Array.

```
ScheduleExtractor scheduleExtractor = new ScheduleExtractor();
scheduleExtractor.execute();

if(myArray.length==0){
   ///
}else{
   //show results
}
```

However, when I try to access the array after calling the method `Asynctask.execute()`, the array has no elements. So, is there a way to make sure that the access to the array happens after finishing the `AsyncTask` method? Thank you.

Comment: if `ScheduleExtractor` is you `AsyncTask` then check `onPostExecute()` check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask`s as the name represents do you job asynchronous, meaning that the call to `execute()` starts the process in a different thread while the rest of your code keeps on running on your own thread right after calling `execute()`.

If you expect your `AsyncTask` to have a final result you should override [`onPostExecute(Result)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onPostExecute(Result)) method and check the length of your array there. Here is a simple example (assuming the final result type is `int[]`:

```
class ScheduleExtractor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, int[]> {
    @Override
    protected int[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Process your retrieved data and return the result here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(int[] arrayResult) {
        if(arrayResult.length==0) {
            // Your code here
        } else {
            // Show results
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sdghasemi, Thank you!